# One pod in Kubernetes cluster crashes but other doesn't

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Strangely, one pod in kubernetes cluster crashes but other doesn't!

```
codingjediweb-6d77f46b56-5mffg   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   3          81s
codingjediweb-6d77f46b56-vcr8q   1/1     Running            0          81s
```

They should both have same image and both should work. What could be reason?

I suspect that the crashing pod has old image but I don't know why. Its because I fixed an issue and expected the code to work (which is on one of the pods).

Is it possible that different pods have different images? Is there a way to check which pod is running which image? Is there a way to "flush" an old image or force K8S to download even if it has a cache?

UPDATE

After Famen's suggestion, I looked at the image. I can see that for the crashing container seem to be using an existing image (which might be old). How can I make K8S always pull an image?

```
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
busybox                          1/1     Running            1          2d1h
codingjediweb-6d77f46b56-5mffg   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   10         29m
codingjediweb-6d77f46b56-vcr8q   1/1     Running            0          29m
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl describe pod codingjediweb-6d77f46b56-vcr8q | grep image
  Normal  Pulling    29m   kubelet, gke-codingjediweb-cluste-default-pool-69be8339-wtjt  Pulling image "docker.io/manuchadha25/codingjediweb:08072020v3"
  Normal  Pulled     29m   kubelet, gke-codingjediweb-cluste-default-pool-69be8339-wtjt  Successfully pulled image "docker.io/manuchadha25/codingjediweb:08072020v3"
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$ kubectl describe pod codingjediweb-6d77f46b56-5mffg | grep image
  Normal   Pulled     28m (x5 over 30m)    kubelet, gke-codingjediweb-cluste-default-pool-69be8339-p5hx  Container image "docker.io/manuchadha25/codingjediweb:08072020v3" already present on machine
manuchadha25@cloudshell:~ (copper-frame-262317)$
```

Also, the working pod has two entries for the image (pulling and pulled). Where are there two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a deployment,  a replicaSet is created in the background. Each pod of that replicaSet has same properties(i.e. images, memory).

When you apply any changes by updating the PodTemplateSpec of the Deployment. A new ReplicaSet is created and the Deployment controller manages the moving  of the Pods from the old ReplicaSet to the new one at a controlled rate. At this point you may find different pods from different replicaSet with differnt properties.

To check the image:

```
# get pod's yaml
$ kubectl get  pods -n <namespace> <pod-name> -o yaml

# get deployment's yaml
$ kubectl get deployments -n <namespace> <deployment-name> -o yaml
```

Set `imagePullPolicy` to `Always` in your deployment yaml,  to use the updated image by forcing a pull.